# ¿Como cuento las letras de las palabras de una cadena de texto en python?

Tags: python, string

Hola buenas necesito hacer el siguiente codigo y no acabo de saber como:

```
Entrada = "Hola me llamo antonio"
Salida = La cadena tiene 4 palabras y la palabra con mas caracteres es antonio
```

De momento llevo hecha la parte de contar las palbras de la cadena la otra parte no encuentro como hacerla

```
text = str(input("Introduce un texto para que sepas cual es la palabra com mas caracteres: "))
word = len(text.split())
print("la cantidad de palabras son ",word)
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: `print(sorted(Entrada.split(), key=lambda x: -len(x))[0])`

Comment: @CandidMoe conviene mas usar min en este caso. Pues sorted crea una lista y almacena todos los datos en memoria.

Comment: @DanteS. Los *one-liners* no pretenden ser eficientes, sino demostrar las posibilidades de Python.

Comment: @DanteS. No se me ocurre como hacerlo con `min()`

Comment: Ya veo. En cuanto a tu segundo comentario: Es lo mismo, pero cambiando sorted por min y quitando el [0] al final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es en lugar de igualar tu variable `words` a solo la longitud, iguálalo a todo el `split`, de esta forma podrás iterar en tu texto

Crear una variable con longitud 0, y luego solo iteras sobre tus palabras, si esta es más grande que tu cadena en la variable, la reemplazas.

```
lenghtest_word = ''
for word in words:
    if len(lenghtest_word) < len(word):
        lenghtest_word = word
```

El código completo quedaría así

```
text = str(input("Introduce un texto para que sepas cual es la palabra com mas caracteres: "))
words =text.split()
lenghtest_word = ''
for word in words:
    if len(lenghtest_word) < len(word):
        lenghtest_word = word
print(f"la cantidad de palabras son {len(words)} y la palabra más larga es {lenghtest_word}")
```

Comment: Hola he comentado el codigo para entenderlo me podrias decir si esta correcto?